# dynamically add new md autocomplete element

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```
<div layout="row" ng-repeat="choice in choices">
        <md-autocomplete
          ng-disabled="autoCompleteOptions.isDisabled"
          md-no-cache="autoCompleteOptions.noCache"
          md-selected-item="autoCompleteOptions.selectedItem"
          md-search-text="autoCompleteOptions.searchText"
          md-items="item in querySearch(fabrics, autoCompleteOptions.searchText, 'fab_id')"
          md-min-length="0"
          md-item-text="item.fab_id"
          placeholder="Search for a Fabric here">
        <md-item-template>
          <span md-highlight-text="autoCompleteOptions.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.fab_id}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
          <md-not-found>
            No FabIds matching "{{autoCompleteOptions.searchText}}" were found.
          </md-not-found>
      </md-autocomplete>
</div>
```

How to create dynamic search-text and selected item variable here? I want these auto complete elements to be distinct but can't figure out a way to pass dynamic names in strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have choices as an array of objects, for each iteration of ng-repeat loop, `choice` is reference to an object in `choices` array. You can have properties like `searchText`, `selectedItem`, `fieldName` in that array. I've created my own example to solve your problem, So your equivalent template can be:

```
<div  ng-repeat="choice in ctrl.choices">
   <md-autocomplete

      md-selected-item = "choice.selectedItem"
      md-search-text-change = "ctrl.searchTextChange(choice.searchText)"
      md-search-text = "choice.searchText"
      md-selected-item-change = "ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
      md-items = "item in ctrl.querySearch(choice.searchText)"
      md-item-text = "item.display"
      md-min-length = "0"
      placeholder = "US State? {{choice.fieldName}}">

      <md-item-template>
         <span md-highlight-text = "choice.searchText"
            md-highlight-flags = "^i">{{item.display}}</span>
      </md-item-template>

      <md-not-found>
         No states matching "{{choice.searchText}}" were found.
      </md-not-found>
   </md-autocomplete>
</div>
```

And in controller along with other functions needed for item teplate data, have this:

```
this.choices = [{searchText: '', selectedItem: '', fieldName: 'Field 1'},
            {searchText: '', selectedItem: '', fieldName: 'Field 2'},
            {searchText: '', selectedItem: '', fieldName: 'Field 3'}];
```

Here's link for plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/hcBtQ45GUY15XUOfjEUr?p=preview